# Worker/Controller реализация многопоточности и интерфейсного класса

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, интерфейс, qthread

> Что с вопросом не так? Почему нет ответа?

Реализовал как мне кажется интерфейсный класс для объектов многопоточности. Вроде все работает, кроме этой строчки, при закрытии.

```
connect(_controller, &IClass::finished, this, [] { qDebug() << "finished"; });
```

1. Хочу в целом узнать, ни изобретаю ли я велосипед.
2. Почему не испускается сигнал `Controller::finished` при удалении объекта (при закрытии окна)?
3. Можно ли сделать сигналы приватными, что бы не создавать `PrivateController`?
4. Делать ли контроллер потомком `IClass`?
5. Советы и предложения.

Ниже код:

## mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
class Worker1;
class Worker2;

// интерфейс класс
class IClass : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    IClass(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
public:
    enum class Types { Worker1, Worker2, };
    static IClass* CreateInstance(Types t, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2(int i) = 0;
    virtual void f3(int x, double y) = 0;
signals:
    void started();
    void finished();
public slots:
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
};

class PrivateController : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    IClass *_w;
public:
    PrivateController(IClass *c, QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), _w(c) {
        connect(this, &PrivateController::f1, _w, &IClass::f1);
        connect(this, &PrivateController::f2, _w, &IClass::f2);
        connect(this, &PrivateController::f3, _w, &IClass::f3);
        connect(this, &PrivateController::stop, _w, &IClass::stop);
    }
    ~PrivateController() override;
    void callF1()                   { emit f1(); }
    void callF2(int i)              { emit f2(i); }
    void callF3(int x, double y)    { emit f3(x, y); }
    void callStop()                 { emit stop(); }
signals:
    void f1();
    void f2(int i);
    void f3(int x, double y);

    // start не нужно реализовывать тк вызывается th->start()
    void stop();
};

class Controller : public IClass {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller(IClass::Types t, QObject *parent = nullptr)
                        : IClass(parent), _w(CreateInstance(t)), _signals(_w) {
        connect(_w, &IClass::started, this, &IClass::started);      // так можно?
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, this, &IClass::finished);    // так можно?
    }
    ~Controller() override;
    void f1() override                  { _signals.f1(); }
    void f2(int i) override             { _signals.f2(i); }
    void f3(int x, double y) override   { _signals.f3(x, y); }
public slots:
    void start() override {
        QThread *th = new QThread;
        _w->moveToThread(th);
        connect(th, &QThread::started, _w, &IClass::start);
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, th, &QThread::quit);
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, th, &QThread::deleteLater);
        connect(_w, &IClass::finished, _w, &IClass::deleteLater);
        th->start();
        qDebug() << "Controller::start";
    }
    void stop() override {
        _signals.stop();
        qDebug() << "Controller::stop";
    }
protected:
    IClass *_w;
    PrivateController _signals;
};

class Worker1 : public IClass {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker1(QObject *parent = nullptr)
                        : IClass(parent) {
        // some code
    }
    void f1() override {
        qDebug() << "Worker1::f1";
    }
    void f2(int i) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker1::f2" << i;
    }
    void f3(int x, double y) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker1::f3" << x << y;
    }
public slots:
    void start() override {
        emit started();
        qDebug() << "Worker1::start";
    }
    void stop() override {
        emit finished();
        qDebug() << "Worker1::stop";
    }
protected:
    // some code
};

class Worker2 : public IClass {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker2(QObject *parent = nullptr)
                        : IClass(parent) {
        // some code
    }
    void f1() override {
        qDebug() << "Worker2::f1";
    }
    void f2(int i) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker2::f2" << i;
    }
    void f3(int x, double y) override {
        qDebug() << "Worker2::f3" << x << y;
    }
public slots:
    void start() override {
        emit started();
        qDebug() << "Worker2::start";
    }
    void stop() override {
        emit finished();
        qDebug() << "Worker2::stop";
    }
protected:
    // some code
};

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    IClass *_controller;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

## mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _controller(new Controller(IClass::Types::Worker2, this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(_controller, &IClass::started, this, [] { qDebug() << "started"; });
    connect(_controller, &IClass::finished, this, [] { qDebug() << "finished"; });
    _controller->start();
    _controller->f1();
    _controller->f2(2);
    _controller->f3(3, 4.4);
//    _controller->stop();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }

PrivateController::~PrivateController() { qDebug() << "~PrivateController()"; }

IClass *IClass::CreateInstance(IClass::Types t, QObject *parent) {
    switch(t) {
    case Types::Worker1: { return new Worker1(parent); }
    case Types::Worker2: { return new Worker2(parent); }
    }
}

Controller::~Controller() { _signals.callStop(); }
```

Вывод приложения:

```
Controller::start
Worker2::start
Worker2::f1
Worker2::f2 2
Worker2::f3 3 4.4
started
~PrivateController()
Worker2::stop
```

Не вывелась строчка `finished`.

Comment: Что такое объекты многопоточности? moveToThread переносит обработку сигналов/слотов в другой поток и уведомляет об этом главный. Для реализации именного выполнения вашего кода в отдельном потоке вам надо Qthread::run.

Comment: дальше я запутался в этих спагетти, что-то где-то неправильно подключено, но распутывать мне лень

Comment: если установлен qt, можно просто запустить

Answer (score 0):

Различные возможные причины вполне подробно [изложены тут](https://www.kdab.com/slot-not-invoked/)

Если попробовать оттуда выделить основное, то:

- Существуют ли объекты на момент коннекта
- Существуют ли объекты на момент вызова emit
- Возможно, нужно гдето явно запустить EventLoop
- Нужно ли регистрировать и зарегестрирован ли MetaType

Ну и посмотреть подробную информацию о сигналах можно при помощи вызова `QObject::dumpObjectInfo()`

Comment: Это размышления ответа только на 2 пункт. На сколько я понял, причина отсутствия `finished`, потому что основной цикл обработки сигналов прекращается прежде чем вызов слота. Если по другому: "плохая идея испускать сигналы дочернего объекта в деструкторе родителя". Но так и до конца не разобрался почему